# Problem with uncontrolled modify every time data is saved in django slug

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create unique slug.I want to create unique slug. I use some methods to generate unique slug,but I have problem with them.

this is my model and my method to create unique slug:

```
#Models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

    def _get_unique_slug(self, slug_input):
        slug = slugify(slug_input)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Curriculum.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:  # Create
            if not self.slug:  # slug is blank
                self.slug = self._get_unique_slug(slug_input=self.title)
            else:  # slug is not blank
                self.slug = self._get_unique_slug(slug_input=self.slug)
        else:  # Update
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug(slug_input=self.slug)
        super(Curriculum, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This method have ***two problem***:

**1. Every time that I save each object(even without modify it)**, slug changes and '-1' append to it.

**2. For some language such as Arabic and Farsi(Persian) slug didn't create.**
how can I fix these problems?

Comment: which django version you use ?

Comment: django 2.2.1 @katoozi

Comment: use slug field like this: `slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True, allow_unicode=True,
        max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Slug'))
`. it support Persian and Arabic

Comment: And delete all my methods ? @katoozi

Comment: yes. for auto fill slug field base on another fields in  admin panel use this: `prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}`.

Comment: I couldn't understand your last comment! Where exactly  `prepopulated_fields` must add? @katoozi

Comment: in your ModelAdmin.

Comment: Thank you. Write your answer to accept it. Last question: Is it necessary to add `null=True, blank=True,` to `slug` field? When I set `makemigrations` django tell me that set default or  change field to null-able field. What I must do ? @katoozi

Comment: it's your choice to let user leave slug blank or null but remember you set it unique field. if you have data in db set the `null=True, blank=True` other wise delete migrations and migrate again.

Comment: Thanks -@katoozi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slug field have allow_unicode:

```
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, allow_unicode=True, max_length=255)
```

prepopulate slug in ModelAdmin:

```
    #admin.py 
    class EditModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
              prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    admin.site.register(ModelName, EditModel)
```

customize slug field data:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

# overwrite your model save method || necessary for : django<1.11.12
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    title = self.title
    # allow_unicode=True for support utf-8 languages
    self.slug = slugify(title, allow_unicode=True)
    super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to overwrite my save method for this goal? @katoozi

Comment: for django<1.11.12 it's necessary. for you no.